# change baud rate of serial port raspberry pi 3 android

Tags: gpio, serial, uart, gps

I installed lineage os 14 on raspberry pi 3 I connected a gps module with UART port, however, the baud rate of GPS is 9600 but baud rate of /dev/ttyS0 is 115200 I want to change the baud rate of ttyS0 in order to read GPS data
I tried stty command

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

However, this won't change the baud rate when I check again with this command
 `stty -F /dev/ttyS0` the speed value is 115200.
How can I change the baud rate of /dev/ttyS0 I also find some solution with serial command `serial /dev/ttyS0 9600` however it doesn't exist on adb shell.Any help would be grateful

Comment: Why don't you set it up in the code that reads the GPS data?

Comment: OK, just saw the `lineage os 14` in your post - sorry for the oversight. I can't help you with lineage, but you should read the [organization's UART documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) as it may "change things" :)

Comment: And finally, FWIW, in Raspbian I can change the speed to 9600 using (nearly) the same command you used: `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600`. Verified using `$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a` -> 
`speed 9600 baud;` ..... etc

Comment: @Seamus I used your solution but it didn't work stty: invalid number 'baud'
I even add a quotation mark for solving this error, the command successfully executed however it doesn't change the baud rate

Comment: Sorry... must be due to diffs between the `lineage`os and `Raspbian` os. If the [organization's UART documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md) didn't explain anything, then I'm afraid I am not equipped to provide any help.